# An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing with

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, time

Trying to get my time synced properly and I run into this error every single ntp server I use.

I've got my firewall disabled, every single port open in my router (UDP and TCP), and I've used several different NTP servers. I've pinged the server to make sure I get a reply, used it, and still get this issue.

Comment: Please update your question adding next facts: 1. Which output from command-line `w32tm /resync`? 2. Some entry (source=`w32Time`, I guess) written to the Event log?

Comment: It works when I run cmd as admin and do w32tm /resync, when I try to update under Adjust Date and Time -> Internet Time -> Change Settings -> Update now, it doesn't work.

Comment: To allow a restricted user to modify the system clock, the system administrator must grant the user specific access to modify the system clock: with Start - Run - `gpedit.msc`. Under `Computer Configuration` section in the left pane, expand the `Windows Settings` folder, expand the `Security Settings` section, expand the `Local Policies` section. Single click on the `User Rights Assignment` section to highlight it, and on the right side look for an entry by the name of `"Change the system time"` in the _Policy_ column. Double click this entry to open the properties window for this entry...

Comment: I'm afraid my previous comment do apply to win-XP, but I hope it should be analogous to Win-7 as well...

Comment: There is no gpedit.msc in windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate editions come with _Group Policy Editor_ installed; however, in some Windows 7 editions (Home Premium, Home Basic and Starter) you could enable it - [by a rough rape](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions)...